# Console.log() receives 2 logs when it should only receive one (addEventListener on querySelector) if string length more equal to 3, do console.log()

Tags: javascript, forms, console, addeventlistener, queryselector

I have a form input field called '#input_code_' + rowNumber

The form field has an eventListener for 'input'.

I only want to activate console.log() when the length of the input value is 3 characters.

I only want 1 instance of console.log() to be outputted.

At the moment the script only output to console.log() when the length of the input value is 3 characters, but the problem is the script creates 2 instances of console.log().

How can I modify the script to output only 1 instance of console.log()?

```
// COUNT COLOR CODE CHARACTERS
function countColorCodeCharacters(rowNumber){

    // Listen to the input for the color code
    document.querySelector('#input_code_' + rowNumber).addEventListener('input', function(e){

        // Get the value of the color code
        colorInput = e.target.value;

        // If the value length is 3, long in console
        if(e.target.value.length === 3) {
            console.log("colorLength: 3");
            console.log("colorValue: " + e.target.value); 
          }
    });
}
```

[Here is a screenshot of the console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuUMB.png)

Comment: You put 2 lines of `console.log()` in the if condition, which returns 2 instances of `console.log()`.

Comment: How many times do you call `countColorCodeCharacters()` with the same row number argument? Can you please create a [mre] of your issue using a code snippet: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992)

Comment: My bad. I had on "oninput" call on the actual form element. So that was calling the function a second time as well as the addEventListener in the scrip. Double the calls, double the output! Derr...


`<input id="input_code_{{$color->fill_id}}" type="text" maxlength="6" oninput="countColorCodeCharacters({{$color->fill_id}})" autofocus>`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

I was trying to figure out why my script was create double the amount of console.log() that it was supposed to.

My script is dependent on the input of a form field.

I realised that I was calling the script twice when a user made an input to that field.

The user input field:

```
<input id="someId" type="text" class="form-control" name="code_5" value="someValue" maxlength="6" oninput="countColorCodeCharacters(5)" autofocus>
```

The function:

```
function countColorCodeCharacters(rowNumber){
    // Listen to the input for the color code
    document.querySelector('#input_code_5')
        .addEventListener('input', function(e){

            // Get the value of the color code
            colorInput = e.target.value;

           // If the value length is 6, long in console
           if(e.target.value.length === 6) {
               console.log("colorLength: 6");
               console.log("colorValue: " + e.target.value); 
           }
    });
}
```

So the function was called "onInput" of the for field, but the function also contained an eventListener for the same form field. So the function ran twice and created double the required instances of console.log().

I removed the eventListener from the function and it now works correctly.

```
// COUNT COLOR CODE CHARACTERS
function countColorCodeCharacters(rowNumber){

    // Get color value for this row
    colorInput = document.getElementById('input_code_' + rowNumber).value;

    // If the color value contains 6 characters...
    if(colorInput.length == 6){
        // Change the color of the box
        changeColorCode(rowNumber, colorInput);
    }
}
```